# CSS match element class element

Tags: css, css-selectors

How do I match all `td` elements in `tr` where `tr` has the class `my-class`?

I've tried

`tr .my-class td`

Also - is it better to fully qualify?

Is `table tbody tr td` better than `td`?

Comment: Just remove the space. `tr.my-class td`

Comment: Damn, now I feel stupid :)

Comment: In css a space is actually a selector: the [descendant selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/descendantselector)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always minimize amount of selectors, so instead of

```
tr.my-class td
```

use just

```
.my-class td
```

Your second question is related to the first one. When you use a following selctor

```
table tbody tr td
```

your browser first matches all `td` elements. Then it checks which of these elements are placed in `tr` element, then checks which are in `tbody` and finally in `table`. Since in properly structured code `td` is always placed in table, there is no need to over-qualify your selectors.

There are many articles on efficiency of CSS selectors, check out this one http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/ for example.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this:

```
.my-class td
```

It's not usually better to fully-qualify in the way you ask. It's called being [over-specific](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

Answer (score 1):

You could either simply do:

```
.my-class td {
    // your css rules here
}
```

Or...

```
tr.my-class td {
    // your css rules here
}
```

Or...

```
table tbody tr.my-class td {
    // your css rules here
}
```

Depends how specific you want/need to be.

I'd recommend that the less css you write the better as long as it works for you.